# Why my HMI is rebooting while entering the foreach loop in program ? C#

Tags: c#

```
void Button3_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        try  
        {  
            string path = (@"Hard Disk\POINTS.txt"); 
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path); 
            int k = 0;
            string[] chartlines = sr.ReadToEnd().Split(new char[]{'\n'});
            foreach(string file in chartlines) 
            { 
                string Chart = chartlines[k]; 
                string xchart = Chart.Split(';')[0]; 
                string ychart = Chart.Split(';')[1];
                int xval = Int32.Parse(xchart); 
                int yval = Int32.Parse(ychart);

                Globals.Tags.X_ARRAY[k].Value = xval;
                Globals.Tags.Y_ARRAY[k].Value = yval; 

                k++;
            } 
            Globals.Tags.CHECK.Value =  Globals.Tags.X_ARRAY[15].Value;
            //check values on screen 
            Globals.Tags.CHECK1.Value = Globals.Tags.Y_ARRAY[15].Value;
        } 
        catch 
        {   
          MessageBox.Show("Error"):
        }  
}
```

The Error is shown everytime I run proogram and no values are set to arrays.Any ideas why ? I write program on iXDeveloper and export it to X2 pro 7 HMI.

Comment: Please show us the exception.

Comment: Thank You for your response and willing to help but the problem is solved.

Comment: Can you post the solution here as an answer? Might help other people who encounter the same problem in the future!